# NUnit Throws Constraint how to assert object's value in a list?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, nunit-3.0

my exception class has a List, contain multiple error messages like this:

```cs
public class MyExceptions : Exception {
    public List<MyValidationError> ValidationErrors { get; set; }
}
public class MyValidationError {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

in my unit test, I want to assert my exception object like this:

```cs
// MyExceptions throws
{
    ValidationErrors: [
        {Name: "field1", Description: "missing field 1"},
        {Name: "field2", Description: "missing field 2"},
    ]
}
```

How can I assert the exception contains `ValidationErrors` with Description "missing field 2"?
What I am trying to do like this (but failed)

```cs
Assert.That(
    () => {
        // do something, throw MyExceptions as above
    },
    Throws.TypeOf<MyExceptions>().And
        .With.Property("ValidationErrors")
        .Has.One.With.Property("Description").EqualTo("missing field 2")
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of clarity, I would split the assertion that a specific exception has been thrown from the assertions of its properties:

```
var exception = Assert.Throws<MyExceptions>(() => {
            // do something, throw MyExceptions as above
        }); 

Assert.That(exception.ValidationErrors.Count, Is.EqualTo(2));
Assert.That(exception.ValidationErrors[0].Name, Is.EqualTo("field 1"));
// etc
```